# PHP able to receive post request with a raw text but its giving error when post same data raw json

Tags: php, json

I'm posting data to my API endpoint. it's simple JSON data. But I'm getting error 404 when posting data as raw JSON but if I post the same data at the same endpoint as raw text its works.

working as raw text

[image: working as raw text]

getting error 404 as raw JSON

[image: getting error 404 as raw JSON]

```
<?php
 
    var_dump(http_response_code());
    echo "hello";
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo file_get_contents("php://input");
```

I have removed all code from the API end point and just trying to print post data.

Sample JSON :

```
{
    "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "456",
            "changes": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
                        "metadata": {
                            "display_phone_number": "123456789",
                            "phone_number_id": 123456789
                        },
                        "contacts": [
                            {
                                "profile": {
                                    "name": "NAME"
                                },
                                "wa_id": 123456789
                            }
                        ],
                        "messages": [
                            {
                                "from": 123456789,
                                "id": "wamid.ID",
                                "timestamp": 123456789,
                                "text": {
                                    "body": "MESSAGE_BODY"
                                },
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "field": "messages"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have checked JSON and it's a valid JSON. no special character but still unable to solve this issue.

One more thing its working on my local machine under XAMPP but not on Linux shared server.

Comment: In the response of your first example (in Postman), there is a `hello` after the response code and before the output of `$_POST`. Where does that string come from? There's nothing in the posted code that would account for it.

Comment: var_dump(http_response_code());
    echo "hello";
    var_dump($_POST);
        echo file_get_contents("php://input");

Comment: Please make sure that the code you post is _exactly_ what you used when you got the result you posted. If not, we can't be sure what's going on.

Comment: Edited question with original code

Comment: I don't really see how this would happen the only difference is the content type and the above is the only code in your test.php, unless the server had some funky settings. You said it's a shared server, have you contacted the server admins/owners to ask if they have some setup that could account for this? The 404 page, is it the web servers standard 404, or is it your apps, or some other custom 404 page?

Comment: i just checked with other json data and its working but still getting error with above json.

Comment: I don't see how the json itself would be the issue since you're not actually parsing it. Is this the only content you have in test.php? There's nothing else loaded? There must be something else going on that we can't see here.

Comment: it's a standard 404 page, not a custom. Already word with server admin they said may the issue with php max_input_var and they increased it to 3000 . But no luck

Comment: That's not relevant here, since you're posting a raw body. If that would affect anything, you would have gotten the same issue when posting it as text. The posted json is also not large enough. Setting it as JSON only changes the content type, nothing else. The data will be sent to the server in exactly the same way, which is why there must be something on the server that causes this.